# How do I set the original size of the image to not exceed the width of the parent container

Tags: javascript, css, image

I want to set the original width of the image, so max-width: 100%, but the width of the parent container of the image is 1000px, and the original size of the image cannot exceed 1000px. I expect the original size of the image to be less than 1000px. If the width of the image is larger than 1000px, set the image size to 1000px

```
img {max-width: 100%, width: 100%};
.container {width: 1000px};
```

I set the `image max-width: 100%` so that the image shows the original size. I set `width: 100%` to keep the original size of the image from exceeding the parent container's 1000px width, but it doesn't work

I expect the original size of the image to be less than 1000px. If the width of the image is larger than 1000px, set the image size to 1000px

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? Maybe even post a codepen?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that setting `max-width: 100%` to `img` if you don't want the image exceed the container.

However, you don't have to set the `img` `width: 100%` in order to show the image in its original size. Simply `width: auto` or you could just skip that because the width of the image is `auto` by default.

`width: 100%` refers to your image will scale to the 100% of the current parent element. Which means `width: 100%` will only make your image scale up or scale down to 1000px width.

Simply take out the `width: 100%`, the [magic](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/yLLVwYZ) is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
img {
   height: 100%,
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```